# MSSQL Trigger After update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, mssql-jdbc

[image: 1]
I have two tables in mssql.
When entering data into a table, the STOCK column in the tiger table should be -1, if the STOCK column is equal to 0, then the STATUS should be false. please help.

When you insert it into the TBLACTION dashboard, it will be triggered on the TBLBOOK dashboard

I speak English poorly. I'm sorry.

Comment: When you post your question on SO. Please provide what you have done till now on your side and where you are stuck. Plus, your question does not say much about your problem

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to *store* data that can be *derived*. Rather than a trigger, think of a view, for instance, that computes the status. When you store derived data, you *introduce* the opportunity for it to be inconsistent with the actual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have multiple solutions for each requirement. Let's try this:

1. When entering data into a table, the STOCK column in the tiger table should be -1
2. if the STOCK column is equal to 0, then the STATUS should be false
3. When you insert it into the TBLACTION dashboard, it will be triggered on the TBLBOOK
   3.a) someone take the book, the column ReturnDate should be NULL on insert;
   3.b) someone return the book then you should update the column ReturnDate

   CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TBLBOOKInserted]
   ON  [dbo].[TBLBOOK]
   AFTER INSERT
   AS
   BEGIN

   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   UPDATE TBLBOOK
   SET
   STOCK = -1
   WHERE
   STOCK IS NULL AND
   ID IN (SELECT INSERTED.ID FROM INSERTED)
   END
   GO

   CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TBLBOOKUpdate]
   ON  [dbo].[TBLBOOK]
   AFTER UPDATE
   AS
   BEGIN

   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   UPDATE TBLBOOK
   SET
   BOOKSTATUS = 0
   WHERE
   STOCK = 0 AND
   ID IN (SELECT INSERTED.ID FROM INSERTED)
   END
   GO

   CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TBLACTIONInsert]
   ON  [dbo].[TBLACTION]
   AFTER INSERT
   AS
   BEGIN

   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   UPDATE TBLBOOK
   SET
   STOCK = STOCK-1
   WHERE
   ID IN (SELECT INSERTED.BOOK FROM INSERTED WHERE RETURNDATE IS NULL)
   END
   GO

   CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TBLACTIONUpdate]
   ON  [dbo].[TBLACTION]
   AFTER UPDATE
   AS
   BEGIN

   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   UPDATE TBLBOOK
   SET
   STOCK = STOCK+1
   WHERE
   ID IN (SELECT INSERTED.BOOK FROM INSERTED WHERE RETURNDATE IS NOT NULL) AND
   ID IN (SELECT DELETED.BOOK FROM DELETED WHERE RETURNDATE IS NULL)
   END
   GO